# Alternative for static method in interface - enforce implementing class-level methods in asp.net custom controls

Tags: .net, asp.net, oop, interface, static

I have a hierarchy in my website project as below:

```
[CustomControl1 - folder]
- CustomControl1.ascx
- CustomControl1.css
- CustomControl1.js
```

I load css and js files dynamicaly based on which controls are used on particular page. I am doing it by using following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomControl1.AddLinks( Page.Header);
    CustomControl2.AddLinks( Page.Header);
    ...
}
```

where `AddLinks` method adds `HtmlLink` controls to `Page.Header` with `href` attribute set to coresponding css and/or js file.

I would like to add Interface that would **force new controls to have AddLinks method** but it is impossible since it is a static method. Because my custom controls inherit from Control class I cannot use abstract class and/or virtual methods either. How can I achieve my goal?

Note:

I know that similar ( about static methods in interfaces) questions was posted on SO before but I didnt found proper solution there. ( or I am too noobish to know that it was a proper solution ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant. I can see exactly why you'd like to have a static method on the interface here to implement your pattern, but c# doesnt allow static methods on interfaces, so your at a dead end here.

Assuming you dont want to just call a method on an instance of your control for some reason, your stuck in either making sure you implement all your static methods, using reflection(smelly) etc.

Why cant you just use

```
 myCustomControl1Instance.AddLinks(Page.Header);
 myCustomControl2Instance.AddLinks(Page.Header);
```

also, personally, I think the control should be smart enough to add the links if its needs them. `Page.ClientScript` contains methods for doing this.

Comment: I dont want to use `controlInstance.Method()` pattern because I add them in UpdatePanel without full postback, after user request any. So I know what controls might be used on page but i dont know when and where. But I will take a look on mentioned `Page.ClientScript`, thanks!

Comment: Bah, `Page.ClientScript` would help me to manage .js files but no .css since I cannot add them in easy, xhtml compatible way.